# Drop Down Menu "Mouseleave"

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make a code but i have some problems with it, when my mouse is going on the "Category 1" is show me the box and i success to make it if the mouse is going to Box ID from Category 1 Button is working but if from Category i move the mouse different place is not hide my Box ... hope someone can help me fix this problem and what i still need if its possible when the mouse leave the Menu Button and Category before to hide the box to wait 1 sec or 2 and if in the 1 or 2 sec the mouse come back on box to show back

This is my js code what i make then right now ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a[id*='DropDown_Menu_ID_']").hover(function() {
  var DropDown_ID        = $(this).attr("id");
  var ID_Split           = DropDown_ID.split('_');
  var Box_Data_ID        = ID_Split[3];

  var Button_Value       = $('#DropDown_Menu_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).attr("value");

  var count              = 0;

  count++;
  $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).show();



  $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).mouseleave(function() {
   count--;
   if (!count) {
    $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).hide();
   }
  });

 });
});
```

I put the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/eANHr/

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/eANHr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[id*='DropDown_Menu_ID_']").hover(function () {

                var DropDown_ID = $(this).attr("id");
                var ID_Split = DropDown_ID.split('_');

                var Box_Data_ID = ID_Split[3];

                var Button_Value = $('#DropDown_Menu_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).attr("value");



                $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).show();
            })
            $("a[id*='DropDown_Menu_ID_']").mouseleave(function () {


                var DropDown_ID = $(this).attr("id");
                var ID_Split = DropDown_ID.split('_');

                var Box_Data_ID = ID_Split[3];
                $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).hide();



            });
        });
```

Comment: i try your code but if my mouse go out from the Menu Button to Box div the Box div will be hide ... is not stay open

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwwe4/)

Simply hide all submenu before showing the right one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[id*='DropDown_Menu_ID_']").hover(function () {
                hideAll();

                var DropDown_ID = $(this).attr("id");
                var ID_Split = DropDown_ID.split('_');
                var Box_Data_ID = ID_Split[3];

                var Button_Value = $('#DropDown_Menu_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).attr("value");

                var count = 0;

                count++;
                $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).show();

                $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).mouseleave(function () {
                    count--;
                    if (!count) {
                        $('#DropDown_Box_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).hide();
                    }
                });

            });

            function hideAll() {
                $('div[id^="DropDown_Box_ID"]').hide();
            }

        });
```

Comment: i try this code is working but the same problem if the mouse if on Menu button and is going to box div menu is remain but if the mouse is going example from menu button to not box div id another part of the website is not hide the box ... the box is hide just if Menu Button - Box Div Menu - Mouse out from Box Div Menu but i need this to Menu Button - Mouse Out ...